# Draw dashed line using turtle graphics

Tags: python, line, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
tt_turtle_obj = Turtle()

for _ in range(15):
    tt_turtle_obj.forward(10)
    tt_turtle_obj.color("white")
    tt_turtle_obj.forward(10)
    tt_turtle_obj.color("black")

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

I used this code to do the same. Is there any other way?

Comment: Instead of changing pen color you could use `.penup` and .`pendown` methods. This way you can draw with any color, over any background.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `turtle.penup()` and `turtle.pendown()` methods, to control when the turtle will draw on the canvas and when it won't. Here is the code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
tt_turtle_obj = Turtle()

for _ in range(15):
    tt_turtle_obj.forward(10)
    tt_turtle_obj.penup()
    tt_turtle_obj.forward(10)
    tt_turtle_obj.pendown()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

This way, you can draw a dashed line over any background and the code can be reused in different scenarios. In the end, both codes do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of turtle.color() try turtle.pencolor() to changes the colour in a line.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
tt_turtle_obj = Turtle()

for _ in range(15):
  tt_turtle_obj.forward(10)
  tt_turtle_obj.pencolor("black")
  tt_turtle_obj.forward(10)
  tt_turtle_obj.pencolor("white")

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to draw a dashed line a specific distance.
By changing the `<dis>` and `<size>` values you can set the distance and the dash size.

```
from turtle import *

###doted line###
for i in range(<dis>):
    if int(i/<size>)%2==1:
        pencolor('white')
    else:
        pencolor('black')
    forward(1)
pencolor('black')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

turtle = Turtle()

for _ in range(50):
    turtle.color("green")
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.pendown()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**